# Delete topleft hint from editext

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

My hint is working but after click edittext hint moving topleft. I don't want topleft hint, I want only one hint. Can anyone help me? I added picture for my problem. I want only one hint. I don't want topleft hint.

```js
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc_message_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_msg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message" />


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_msg"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="22dp"
        android:hint="This is my cool hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/floatingActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93QLJ.png)

Comment: Use `<EditText>` tag instead of `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below code,

```
// remove hint from `TextInputLayout`
((TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.tv_msg)).setHint(null);
// set the hint back on the `EditText`
// The passed `String` could also be a string resource
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText)).setHint("This is my cool hint.");
```

OR

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tv_msg"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="22dp"
    android:hint=" "
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/floatingActionButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:hint="This is my cool hint"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```